# Is this Image about the outer dimensions of the TARDIS official?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

I recently got a T-Shirt with the following print:
[image: Outer Dimensions of the TARDIS]
Now i am wondering if these are official measurements which were/are used by the BBC to build the *TARDIS* or if they are estimates. I already searched for offical measurments but i wasn't able to find anything useful.

Comment: It *looks* right, accounting for avg height of the mostly human or human-appearing, but I don't know where you'd find an official source either.

Comment: This appears to be a fan-work but one that's based on the original artists blueprints; https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/5d/4d/f7/5d4df7c3d57f8812ae5238fdfa0800c6.jpg

Comment: Note that the current TARDIS does not have the same dimensions as those used in previous series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The measurements are accurate and look as though they are taken from the 2004/2005 plans drawn by Stephen Nicholas for BBC CYMRU WWALES.

[image: Tardis Plans 2004/2005 Stephen Nicholas]

[image: Tardis Plans 2004/2005 Stephen Nicholas]

These plans were on display at the Doctor Who Experience in Cardiff